# Mysql sum a column group by id, then divide that sum for each id with value from another column in another table with the matching id for each row

Tags: mysql, database, loops

Mysql problem: my company sells grain. We buy a big bulk shipment of grain and sell it in small size packets. Each bulk shipment we receive has its own lot number with other data tied to that number as well.

I have an inventory table and a product variant table.

[Sample of Warehouse_inventory_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snCsO.png)

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>inventoryid</th><th>productid   </th><th>weight</th><th>batch</th><th>location</th><th>lot</th><th> </th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>1203</td><td>16134</td><td>0.000</td><td>1</td><td>LC Bucket</td><td>S1090</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1882</td><td>16137</td><td>0.000</td><td>1</td><td>Small Cargo</td><td>S1025</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>603</td><td>16138</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>254-03-901</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2695</td><td>16138</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>254-03-002-1</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>4086</td><td>16138</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>G-500-WD</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>4582</td><td>16138</td><td>150.000</td><td>2</td><td>Bulk Cargo</td><td>2373</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>4879</td><td>16138</td><td>30.885</td><td>1</td><td>LC Bucket</td><td>2373</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3382</td><td>16139</td><td>1.516</td><td>1</td><td>On Shelf</td><td>S1520</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>256</td><td>16141</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>F6411</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1963</td><td>16141</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>P6611</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2090</td><td>16141</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>P6389</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3470</td><td>16141</td><td>12.588</td><td>1</td><td>LC Bucket</td><td>N3915</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>4526</td><td>16141</td><td>27.000</td><td>2</td><td>Bulk Cargo</td><td>N3915</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>233</td><td>16142</td><td>6.991</td><td>1</td><td>LC Bucket</td><td>20701</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>281</td><td>16142</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>23055</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1065</td><td>16142</td><td>50.000</td><td>4</td><td>Bulk Cargo</td><td>20123</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2479</td><td>16142</td><td>30.821</td><td>3</td><td>Bulk Cargo</td><td>P6005</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2097</td><td>16143</td><td>0.000</td><td>1</td><td>LC Bucket</td><td>34294</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>665</td><td>16144</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>W3178</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1752</td><td>16144</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>12646</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3629</td><td>16144</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>LC Bucket</td><td>M3386-1</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>4564</td><td>16144</td><td>28.000</td><td>2</td><td>Bulk Cargo</td><td>M3386-1</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>4830</td><td>16144</td><td>13.971</td><td>1</td><td>LC Bucket</td><td>M3386-1</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>243</td><td>16146</td><td>26.750</td><td>2</td><td>Bulk Cargo</td><td>D3302</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>656</td><td>16146</td><td>1.444</td><td>1</td><td>LC Bucket</td><td>D3302</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3637</td><td>16146</td><td>50.000</td><td>3</td><td>Bulk Cargo</td><td>34636</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1531</td><td>16149</td><td>0.000</td><td>0</td><td>Archived</td><td>S1086</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2735</td><td>16149</td><td>46.000</td><td>3</td><td>Bulk Cargo</td><td>18/64</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3128</td><td>16149</td><td>0.000</td><td>1</td><td>SC Bucket</td><td>S1528</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>3129</td><td>16149</td><td>1.238</td><td>2</td><td>SC Bucket</td><td>S1555</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

[Sample of Variants_Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9mLw.png)

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>variantid</th><th>productid</th><th>avail</th><th>weight</th><th>package_weight</th></tr><tr><td>404</td><td>16142</td><td>224</td><td>0.013</td><td>0.009</td></tr><tr><td>405</td><td>16142</td><td>8</td><td>0.280</td><td>0.270</td></tr><tr><td>409</td><td>16142</td><td>10</td><td>1.100</td><td>1.100</td></tr><tr><td>450</td><td>16141</td><td>225</td><td>0.006</td><td>0.002</td></tr><tr><td>509</td><td>16144</td><td>126</td><td>0.011</td><td>0.007</td></tr><tr><td>511</td><td>16144</td><td>10</td><td>0.074</td><td>0.070</td></tr><tr><td>512</td><td>16144</td><td>10</td><td>0.280</td><td>0.270</td></tr><tr><td>620</td><td>16138</td><td>110</td><td>0.039</td><td>0.035</td></tr><tr><td>622</td><td>16138</td><td>16</td><td>0.280</td><td>0.270</td></tr><tr><td>623</td><td>16138</td><td>12</td><td>1.100</td><td>1.100</td></tr><tr><td>917</td><td>16142</td><td>2</td><td>5.300</td><td>5.200</td></tr><tr><td>979</td><td>16146</td><td>10</td><td>1.100</td><td>1.100</td></tr><tr><td>1157</td><td>16144</td><td>11</td><td>1.100</td><td>1.100</td></tr><tr><td>1158</td><td>16144</td><td>5</td><td>5.300</td><td>5.200</td></tr><tr><td>3644</td><td>16138</td><td>6</td><td>5.300</td><td>5.200</td></tr><tr><td>3645</td><td>16138</td><td>2</td><td>26.000</td><td>25.500</td></tr><tr><td>3646</td><td>16138</td><td>1</td><td>52.000</td><td>51.000</td></tr><tr><td>3917</td><td>16141</td><td>11</td><td>0.074</td><td>0.070</td></tr><tr><td>3918</td><td>16141</td><td>8</td><td>0.280</td><td>0.270</td></tr><tr><td>3919</td><td>16141</td><td>13</td><td>1.100</td><td>1.100</td></tr><tr><td>3920</td><td>16141</td><td>2</td><td>5.300</td><td>5.200</td></tr><tr><td>3997</td><td>16143</td><td>6</td><td>0.011</td><td>0.007</td></tr><tr><td>4000</td><td>16143</td><td>0</td><td>0.074</td><td>0.070</td></tr><tr><td>4001</td><td>16143</td><td>0</td><td>0.280</td><td>0.270</td></tr><tr><td>4002</td><td>16143</td><td>0</td><td>1.100</td><td>1.100</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The columns I need to work with are weight from inventory table, and the package_weight and avail column from the variant table.

I'm tring to update the avail column for each variantid to show how many packets are available for each size, based off the summed weight of the different lots of the same product id in the inventory table.

Each product size has its own variantid in the variants table which is tied to the productid in the inventory table.(has a column named productid in variants table). Each variantid has has its own `package_weight` column that has its packet size weight in lbs.

The problem im trying to solve with SQL code is

We need to find out the total amount of seeds we have in pounds for each seed product id, and show how many packets are available for each different size variant at the moment and put that in the avail column for each different size variant of each product.

I wrote a simple SQL query to get the total weight, from different lot numbers that have matching productid's from the inventory table. This works fine but I'm lost on the next step.

```
SELECT productid, SUM(weight) 
FROM warehouse_inventory 
GROUP BY productid;
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>productid</th><th>SUM(weight)</th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>16134</td><td>0.000</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>16137</td><td>0.000</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>16138</td><td>180.885</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>16139</td><td>1.516</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>16141</td><td>39.588</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>16142</td><td>87.812</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>16143</td><td>0.000</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>16144</td><td>41.971</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>16146</td><td>78.194</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>16149</td><td>47.238</td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Now I need to then take that result, which has totals for each productid, and divide each products total by the smaller sized packet weight to show how many of that size packet are available for each different size variantid's package_weight with matching productid's.

For example:

to find how many 1oz winter rye packets are available right now we take the total weight we have, 2000 lbs of winter rye grain, and divide it by its package_weight .07 lbs(1oz), which shows we have 28571 packets available.

How do I put that available amount into the avail column in variants table?

I'm new to SQL, but I was trying something like this:

```
INSERT INTO variants(avail) 
VALUES(@updated_variant_amount_avail)

SET @product_total_weight := (SELECT i.productid, SUM(weight) 
                              FROM warehouse_inventory AS i
                              GROUP BY i.productid;)

INNER JOIN variants AS v ON v.productid = i.productid

SET @updated_variant_amount_avail := SUM(@product_total_weight /v.package_weight)
```

Not sure if this is possible with just sql. I was looking into stored procedures and was wondering if i should look into trying this going that route. Or is there a better solution ? Should I be trying to do this with just mysql?

Also, this needs to run like once or twice a day so i was going to make a mysql event. is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
select productid as 'Product',
       sum(weight) as 'Total weight',
       (sum(weight) / InF2.package_weight)  as 'Packets'
  From TABLE_containing_totalweights as InF1
  Left Join TABLE_containing_packetweights as InF2
    On InF1.productID = InF2.productID
```

Comment: That doesn't get the results im looking for. I trying to get the sum of each product amount and update the "avail" column of all the variantid rows with the same matching productid to show how much of each variant of the same product is left. i added samples of the tables im working with